# How to rename output.library option for each entry point in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I'd like to compile multiple entry points with Webpack, but it applies the same library name to all of the output bundles. I'd like for each bundle to have a different library name.

For example, here's part of my webpack.config.js:

```
entry: {
    app: "./src/app.tsx",
    editor: "./src/modes/editor.ts",
},

output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'),
    filename: "[name].js",
    libraryTarget: 'amd',
    library: 'app',
},
```

Each bundle uses the `output.library` option ("app"), but I want each bundle to use a different library name.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it is not documented on the website, but this example shows how: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library

Basically, just put `[name]` in there: `library: '[name]'` (similar to the `filename` option).